# Java Secure password generator with high entropy

Tags: java, security, password-manager, progressive-web-application

What is the best Java password generator library that we can use to generate the good passwords that humans can use to login to an account.

I have a scenario where I’m trying to reduce the password length to just “10-13” characters where user can see and type . However, we need that to be most secure with high password entropy ( prefer to have alpha-numerical & symbol). And make sure that the library create new password every time and doesn’t use any compromised list of passwords.

Example:

1. apple keychain suggests a password that can used when I try to signup with secure entropy.
2. using something like keypass as a library to create new passwords. Do we have any library in Java as such.
3. temp password is created by application and shared to user to login using them.

I had some research done Md landed on

https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn

which I’m not sure if it does work in my case because, since my application  is generating the password for my user and not checking the password user is selecting for entropy.

Comment: I don't think that it is necessary to build a library for this functionality. Using Java's `SecureRandom` in combination with an array or String that contains the allowed characters for the password you can build a password generator in my be 5 lines of Java code.